# python: Creating a dictionary from a Text File: input short text and return long text

Tags: python, dictionary

The file “Textese.txt” contains a word and its translation into textese. I need to write a program to create a dictionary with the file, ask the user to enter a simple sentence then translate it into textese.

for example, input 'b4', the program should return 'before'. I know I need to use the define function and translate method, but I don't know how to put it together.

the file looks like:

```
before,b4
busy,bz
computer,puter
definitely,def
easy,ez
energy,nrg
enjoy,njoy
enough,nuff
everyone,every1
excellent,xlnt
favorite,fav
```

Comment: "I need to write a program" is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tkinter` for such program. Assuming your `data.txt` is following:

```
efore,b4
busy,bz
computer,puter
definitely,def
easy,ez
energy,nrg
enjoy,njoy
enough,nuff
everyone,every1
excellent,xlnt
```

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.dictionary = {}
        with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.read().rstrip().split('\n'):
                value, key = line.split(',')
                self.dictionary[key] = value

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='Translate', command=self.translate)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def translate(self):
        result = self.dictionary.get(self.entry.get())
        if result:
            self.lbl.configure(text=result)
        else:
            self.lbl.configure(text='Translation not found')

App()
```

Output:

[image]

Command line based script:

```
dictionary = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().rstrip().split('\n'):
        value, key = line.split(',')
        dictionary[key] = value

word = input('Enter word: ')
result = dictionary.get(word)
if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print('Translation not found')
```

Output:

```
Enter word: ez
easy
```

Comment: thank you! but i got an error from the Command line based script: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)?

Comment: Please share text file you're using

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ozkrK9Oo3kaSmyu2-1rUFsQbCQNhxTO6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that is the format of your file, it seems to me that each word/translation couple are separated by a comma, and each pair is separated from other pairs by a newline (or more than one). You could read the data from the file into a single string, then use `yourstring.split("\n")` to obtain a list where each element is in the form "word,textese", then loop through each one of these element and split each again, this time using the comma as delimiter (`element.split(",")`). Read [this](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-file-into-a-dictionary-in-python) if you want to know how to convert every word and its associated translation into 'key-value' dictionary.

Comment: Hi I think my approach is similar to yours, I tried this:

enter = input('Enter a simple sentence: ')

userEnter = []
file = open('Textese.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    if enter in line:
        userEnter.append(line.strip('\n'))

print(userEnter)

the result is ['before,b4'], how can I make it just before? thanks!

Comment: I can't properly read your test because formatting in comments produces typos. Try the implementation given by @RustamGarayev, I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert those pairs into dictionary `key/value` pair:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    output = f.read().splitlines()

converter_dict = {each_word.split(',')[1]: each_word.split(',')[0] for each_word in output}
# -> {'b4': 'before', 'bz': 'busy', 'puter': 'computer', ...}
```

After taking `user_input`, you can split input into words and check if there is any matching `key/value` pair in dictionary:

```
# assuming user input will always be separated by space
user_input = "def nuff nrg"
words = user_input.split()
# -> ['def', 'nuff', 'nrg']

# Get value of each word from dict if it exists, else return None
result = [converter_dict.get(word, None) for word in words]
# -> ['definitely', 'enough', 'energy']
```

Lastly, you need to convert that list into a single string:

```
# Convert list of words into a single string
sentence = ' '.join(result)
# -> 'definitely enough energy'
```